# How to escape reserved words in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this piece of code in JavaScript (jQuery):

```
$("<a />").html("?").attr({
    href: "javascript:void();",
    class: "CorrentTooltip",
    title: "Explain!"
});
```

What are the alternatives to escape reserved word `class`?

ps.: The option `class` is causing a mess with my Javascript Parser in my IDE (Visual Studio) due to conflict with keyword `class`. So, the JS Parser says that there's a lot of syntax errors after this point. I can't collapse code blocks. It continues functional, but ugly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can escape it by enclosing it using `''` or `""`

```
$("<a />").html("?").attr({
    href: "javascript:void();",
    'class': "CorrentTooltip",
    title: "Explain!"
});
```